# H2O: Cannot read LARGE model from disk via `h2o.loadModel`

Tags: r, linux, h2o

- **UPDATED 28Jun2017, below, in response to @Michal Kurka.**
- **UPDATED 26Jun2017, below.**

I am unable to load a large GBM model that I saved in native H2O format (ie, hex).

- H2O v3.10.5.1
- R v3.3.2
- Linux 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 GNU/Linux

My goal is to eventually save this model as MOJO.

This model was so large that I had to initialize H2O with min/max memory 100G/200G before H2O's model training would run successfully.

This is how I trained the GBM model:

```
localH2O <- h2o.init(ip = 'localhost', port = port, nthreads = -1,
                     min_mem_size = '100G', max_mem_size = '200G')

iret <- h2o.gbm(x = predictors, y = response, training_frame = train.hex,
                validation_frame = holdout.hex, distribution="multinomial",
                ntrees = 3000, learn_rate = 0.01, max_depth = 5, nbins = numCats,
                model_id = basename_model)

gbm <- h2o.getModel(basename_model)
oPath <- h2o.saveModel(gbm, path = './', force = TRUE)
```

The training data contains 81,886 records with 1413 columns. Of these columns, 19 are factors.  The vast majority of these columns are 0/1.

```
$ wc -l training/*.txt
     81887 training/train.txt
     27294 training/holdout.txt
```

This is the saved model as written to disk:

`$ ls -l`

```
total 37G
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bfo7328 37G Jun 22 19:57 my_model.hex
```

This is how I tried to read the model from disk using the same large memory allocation values 100G/200G:

`$ R`

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31) -- "Sincere Pumpkin Patch"
Copyright (C) 2016 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)

> library(h2o)
> localH2O=h2o.init(ip='localhost', port=65432, nthreads=-1,
                  min_mem_size='100G', max_mem_size='200G')

H2O is not running yet, starting it now...

Note:  In case of errors look at the following log files:
    /tmp/RtmpVSwxXR/h2o_bfo7328_started_from_r.out
    /tmp/RtmpVSwxXR/h2o_bfo7328_started_from_r.err

openjdk version "1.8.0_121"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

Starting H2O JVM and connecting: .. Connection successful!

R is connected to the H2O cluster: 
    H2O cluster uptime:         3 seconds 550 milliseconds 
    H2O cluster version:        3.10.5.1 
    H2O cluster version age:    13 days  
    H2O cluster name:           H2O_started_from_R_bfo7328_kmt050 
    H2O cluster total nodes:    1 
    H2O cluster total memory:   177.78 GB 
    H2O cluster total cores:    64 
    H2O cluster allowed cores:  64 
    H2O cluster healthy:        TRUE 
    H2O Connection ip:          localhost 
    H2O Connection port:        65432 
    H2O Connection proxy:       NA 
    H2O Internal Security:      FALSE 
    R Version:                  R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
```

From `/tmp/RtmpVSwxXR/h2o_bfo7328_started_from_r.out`:

```
INFO: Processed H2O arguments: [-name, H2O_started_from_R_bfo7328_kmt050, -ip, localhost, -port, 65432, -ice_root, /tmp/RtmpVSwxXR]
INFO: Java availableProcessors: 64
INFO: Java heap totalMemory: 95.83 GB
INFO: Java heap maxMemory: 177.78 GB
INFO: Java version: Java 1.8.0_121 (from Oracle Corporation)
INFO: JVM launch parameters: [-Xms100G, -Xmx200G, -ea]
INFO: OS version: Linux 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 (amd64)
INFO: Machine physical memory: 1.476 TB
```

My call to `h2o.loadModel`:

```
if ( TRUE ) {
  now <- format(Sys.time(), "%a %b %d %Y %X")
  cat( sprintf( 'Begin %s\n', now ))

  model_filename <- './my_model.hex'
  in_model.hex <- h2o.loadModel( model_filename )

  now <- format(Sys.time(), "%a %b %d %Y %X")
  cat( sprintf( 'End   %s\n', now ))
}
```

From `/tmp/RtmpVSwxXR/h2o_bfo7328_started_from_r.out`:

```
INFO: GET /, parms: {}
INFO: GET /, parms: {}
INFO: GET /, parms: {}
INFO: GET /3/InitID, parms: {}
INFO: Locking cloud to new members, because water.api.schemas3.InitIDV3
INFO: POST /99/Models.bin/, parms: {dir=./my_model.hex}
```

After waiting an hour, I see these "out of memory" (OOM) error messages:

```
INFO: POST /99/Models.bin/, parms: {dir=./my_model.hex}
#e Thread WARN: Swapping!  GC CALLBACK, (K/V:24.86 GB + POJO:112.01 GB + FREE:40.90 GB == MEM_MAX:177.78 GB), desiredKV=22.22 GB OOM!
#e Thread WARN: Swapping!  GC CALLBACK, (K/V:26.31 GB + POJO:118.41 GB + FREE:33.06 GB == MEM_MAX:177.78 GB), desiredKV=22.22 GB OOM!
#e Thread WARN: Swapping!  GC CALLBACK, (K/V:27.36 GB + POJO:123.03 GB + FREE:27.39 GB == MEM_MAX:177.78 GB), desiredKV=22.22 GB OOM!
#e Thread WARN: Swapping!  GC CALLBACK, (K/V:28.21 GB + POJO:126.73 GB + FREE:22.83 GB == MEM_MAX:177.78 GB), desiredKV=22.22 GB OOM!
```

I would not expect to need so much memory to read the model from disk.

How can I read this model from disk into memory.  And once I do, can I save it as a MOJO?

---

**UPDATE 1: 26Jun2017**

I just noticed that the disk size of a GBM model increased dramatically between versions of H2O:

```
H2O v3.10.2.1:
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 169M Jun 19 07:23 my_model.hex

H2O v3.10.5.1:
    -rw-rw-r-- 1  37G Jun 22 19:57 my_model.hex
```

Any ideas why?  Could this be the root of the problem?

---

**UPDATE 2: 28Jun2017 in response to comments by @Michal Kurka.**

When I load the training data via `fread`, the class (type) of each column is correct:
*   24 columns are ‘character’;
* 1389 columns are ‘integer’ (all but one column are 0/1);
* 1413 total columns.

I then convert the R-native data frame to an H2O data frame and manually factor-ize 20 columns:

```
train.hex <- as.h2o(df.train, destination_frame = "train.hex”)
length(factorThese)
[1] 20
train.hex[factorThese] <- as.factor(train.hex[factorThese])
str(train.hex)
```

A condensed version of the output from `str(train.hex)`, showing only those 19 columns that are factors (1 factor is the response column):

```
 - attr(*, "nrow")= int 81886
 - attr(*, "ncol")= int 1413
 - attr(*, "types")=List of 1413
  ..$ : chr "enum" : Factor w/ 72 levels
  ..$ : chr "enum" : Factor w/ 77 levels
  ..$ : chr "enum" : Factor w/ 51 levels
  ..$ : chr "enum" : Factor w/ 4226 levels
  ..$ : chr "enum" : Factor w/ 4183 levels
  ..$ : chr "enum" : Factor w/ 3854 levels
  ..$ : chr "enum" : Factor w/ 3194 levels
  ..$ : chr "enum" : Factor w/ 735 levels
  ..$ : chr "enum" : Factor w/ 133 levels
  ..$ : chr "enum" : Factor w/ 16 levels
  ..$ : chr "enum" : Factor w/ 25 levels
  ..$ : chr "enum" : Factor w/ 647 levels
  ..$ : chr "enum" : Factor w/ 715 levels
  ..$ : chr "enum" : Factor w/ 679 levels
  ..$ : chr "enum" : Factor w/ 477 levels
  ..$ : chr "enum" : Factor w/ 645 levels
  ..$ : chr "enum" : Factor w/ 719 levels
  ..$ : chr "enum" : Factor w/ 678 levels
  ..$ : chr "enum" : Factor w/ 478 levels
```

The above results are exactly the same between v3.10.2.1 (smaller model written to disk: 169M) and v3.10.5.1 (larger model written to disk: 37G).

The actual GBM training uses `nbins <- 37`:

```
numCats <- n_distinct(as.matrix(dplyr::select_(df.train,response)))
numCats
[1] 37

iret <- h2o.gbm(x = predictors, y = response, training_frame = train.hex,
          validation_frame = holdout.hex, distribution="multinomial",
          ntrees = 3000, learn_rate = 0.01, max_depth = 5, nbins = numCats,
          model_id = basename_model)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference in size of the models (169M vs 37G) is surprising. Can you please make sure that H2O recognizes all your numeric columns as numeric and not categorical with very high cardinality?

Do you use automatic detection of column types or do you specify it manually?

Comment: I replied to your questions in the body of my original question, under the section **UPDATE 2: 28Jun2017 in response to comments by @Michal Kurka.**  Thank you for looking into this.  We are unable to continue with this project until we can get this problem resolved.

Comment: Thank you for adding this information. We didn't observe similar behavior with other users. Would you be able to share an anonymized version of the dataset with H2O so that we can reproduce it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Michal Kurka.  Would you mind speaking to Josephine Wang?  She and I have spoken in the past.  It would probably be more informative to speak with her vs what I could type.  Please feel free to contact me via voice if you prefer.  Thanks.

Comment: Sure, no problem

Comment: A thought: perhaps the large increase in model size (169M vs 37G) is related to the number of distinct values in categorical data?

Comment: We found a bug in H2O that caused increased memory usage and increased size of the serialized models, fixed in latest fix release: http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-vajda/4/index.html

Please download version 3.10.5.4 and let me know if it helped resolve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for this fix.  Yes, this has resolved my problem.